# Reduce Boolean Expression

Tags: boolean-algebra

Note:

A B = A and B

A + B = A or B

The expression:

```
r = a̅ c̅ b + a̅ c b̅ + a c̅ b̅ + a c b
```

Simplify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to optimize this expression further and reduce the number of terms.

The [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Karnaugh_map):

```
             ab
       00  01  11  10
      +---+---+---+---+
   0  | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
c     +---+---+---+---+
   1  | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
      +---+---+---+---+
```

There are no adjacent `1` terms which can be merged into [minterms](http://www.dsm.fordham.edu/~moniot/Classes/CompOrganization/boolean-outline/node4.html) with fewer literals. In fact, the expression is the three-input exclusive or of `a`, `b` and `c`. Output `r` is true if an odd number of inputs is true.